# Can not find out why 'NullReference Exception' is thorwn

Tags: vb.net, winforms, exception, telerik

I have a Telerik Tabbed PageView in my Windows Form application which I can edit tab's titles by double clicking on them which initiates a text editor. Following subs are taking care of altered labels - check the edited labels not to be blank:

```
Private Sub ViewElement_EditorInitialized(sender As Object, e As UI.RadPageViewEditorEventArgs)
    AddHandler MountingSystemTabControl.ViewElement.ActiveEditor.Validating, AddressOf ActiveEditor_Validating
    AddHandler MountingSystemTabControl.ViewElement.ActiveEditor.Validated, AddressOf ActiveEditor_Validated
    AddHandler MountingSystemTabControl.ViewElement.ActiveEditor.ValidationError, AddressOf ActiveEditor_ValidationError
End Sub

Private Sub ActiveEditor_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs)
    Dim editor As UI.RadPageViewElement.PageViewItemTextEditor = TryCast(sender, UI.RadPageViewElement.PageViewItemTextEditor)
    If editor IsNot Nothing AndAlso MountingSystemTabControl.ViewElement.ActiveEditor.Value = String.Empty Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ActiveEditor_ValidationError(sender As Object, e As UI.ValidationErrorEventArgs)
    RadMessageBox.Show("Array label can't be empty!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.[Error])
End Sub

Private Sub ActiveEditor_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RadMessageBox.Show("Array label has been successfully updated!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Info)
End Sub
```

Moreover, this line is there in my Form_Load event:

```
AddHandler MountingSystemTabControl.ViewElement.EditorInitialized, AddressOf ViewElement_EditorInitialized
```

Now the problem is, whenever I run the code, after the MessageBox shows me the "*Array label has been successfully updated*!" message, a **NullReference Exception** is thrown which it seems I can't catch it not even with Application Event handlers ! After breaking the code, Visual Studio refers me to this line as the source of the exception:

```
RadMessageBox.Show("Array label has been successfully updated!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Info)
```

And that's what confuses me because I can't find anything referenced in that line (of course there is something but I don't know what).

[Call Stack screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edo6j.jpg)

[Main idea of the code](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/pageview-how-to-editing-page-tabs.html).

Comment: You should be able to post the stack trace for the exception in question.

Comment: Not sure whether I got what you meant or not but here is the screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/RnK9lJc.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was addressed by updating to  'Telerik UI for WinForms Q1 2015 (version **2015.1.225**)'

Answer (score 0):

As memory serves...I think RadMessageBox calls for a Parent argument.

Try this:

```
RadMessageBox.Show(Me, "Array label has been successfully updated!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, RadMessageIcon.Info)
```